# How to create a .tmx file "data"?

Tags: file, tmx

I am currently trying to create a random map using tileD but I couldn't manage to decode the "data" in the .tmx file. I read that the data is base64 encode and gzip compressed but none (of what I've searched) actually has got some useful results.

Has anyone successfully decoded the "data"? Can I have a full example of how the "data" looks like in xml?

If anyone knows what is the format for creating the "data" in XML can you share with us?

Comment: Hi all, sorry if anyone found this question lame, anyway I just found out you can simply save a .tmx without any compression, i.e. just xml under the preferences in TileD.

Answer (score 0):

The entire format for Tiled's .tmx format can be found here:
https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format